# When there are fatal git clone errors, fetch-pack invalid index-pack output is produced

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, fetch

I created a new ec2 instance, however
when I try to clone a git url in html folder
following error is shown:

```
pack-reused 3 , 

fatal: **fetch-pack**: invalid index-pack output


**clone git url not created project folder **
```

I tried following alternatives:

```
git config --global core.compression 0

git clone --depth 1 < git url >
```

shown project folder

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

output:  not fetched remote origin

```
git pull origin branch 

failed error : fetch-pack invalid index-pack 

git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m
```

same output error fetch-pack invalid index-pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your [ec2 T3 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/).
As noted by **[Dan Langille](https://twitter.com/DLangille)**

> This instance type, `t3.small`, cannot clone the git repo.
>
> ```
> Receiving objects: 100% (4907825/4907825), 1.13 GiB | 13.65 MiB/s, done.
> fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
> ```
>
> I seem to recall this problem from earlier attempts with other repos.
> I'll try `t3.medium` with 4GB RAM.
>
> Success.
> It seems the minimum level for `git clone` is `t3.medium`.

Comment: I already have a t2.micro instance, but the git clone is t2.micro, and it was successfully cloned without error. fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output. I tried git clone again with another newly created t2.micro instance and received the same fatal error: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Comment: @Venkatesh Did you try with a t2.medium instead?

Comment: no , im not try t3.medium . its free tier account

Comment: @Venkatesh Do you have a `t2.medium` in the free tier account? If not, I suspect `micro` is not well suited to reliably clone a Git repository.

Comment: ok . However, my other git repository successfully cloned t2.micro with no errors. Why did this particular git repo clone fail? How to fix the solutions

Comment: @Venkatesh Possibly because that git repository is too big. Can you can try, for testing, a git shallow clone: `git clone --depth=1 https://...`

Comment: I've tried it before , git clone creates a project folder, but we can not do this checkout, list all branches, and git fetch. Do not pull from another branch! What I can do

Comment: @Venkatesh Once you have clone with depth 1, try and increase the depth progressively, using [`git fetch --depth=2`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---depthltdepthgt) (then 3, 4, and so on). Again for testing.

Comment: I tried git fetch --depth=2 to 5, but it was no use. Finally, didn't the other solution change the instance type to t2.medium

Comment: Ok, so why is t2.medium git clone working, but what is the reason for t2.micro not cloning?

Comment: @Venkatesh Probably because t2.medium has 4GB RAM as opposed to t2.micro (which has only 1GB RAM)

Comment: ram-based git clone? However, I already have a t2.micro with 1 GB RAM that works with the same git repo.

Comment: @Venkatesh But you just said "what is the reason for t2.micro not cloning?" So it does not work with a t2.micro, yes? Or at least, it does not work reliably.

Comment: so this git clone issue project repo storage size or instane type memory size issue ??

Comment: @Venkatesh Yes, the type of resources (storage/memory) of the ec2 T3 or T2 instance does matter for `git clone` to succeed.

Comment: Is it due to a memory issue or instance features, I had a similar problem?

Comment: @ThomasStokes Possible. Did you check with [the support](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/)?